# Challenging Transition from Vertical to Horizontal Faces

Tags: mesh, objects, edges, topology, shadows

I'm trying to make a transition from vertical to horizontal faces, but I have no idea how to do it without causing shading issues. I've never seen the pattern like this before and I didn't find anything simular on the Internet. My knowledge of blender are too bad to deal with it by myself. Here is an example of how it should look like if it is done correctly:[image][image] *I've been trying to fix it for three days, but I haven't seen any progress. Can someone take a look at it.*

[image]

Comment: Hello, the object you share doesn't seem to be exactly the same as the one you show? Also do you have a pircture of the reference model? It looks like there are 2 things here, the transition to flat and the transition from a sharp edge to a smooth one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a try, the topology before:

[image]

The topology after. If the edge needs to be sharper, slide the adjacent edges closer to it:

[image]

Once you give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

File: [image]

Comment: Wow!! It looks really nice. Can you please share the edited file?

Comment: Sure: https://blend-exchange.com/b/q4dz6pv6